# Php preg_match help

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to find a php preg_match that can match

test1 test2[...] but not test1 test2 [...]

and return test2(...) as the output as $match.

I tried

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9][\[](.*)[\]]$/i',"test1 test2[...]", $matches);
```

But it matches both cases and return the full sentence.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: More details on the example please!

Comment: Is "test1 test2[...] but not test1 test2 [...]" a string or an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match('/([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\[][^\]]+[\]])$/i',"test1 test2[...]", $matches);
```

notice the `+` after `[a-zA-Z0-9]` it says one or more alpha numeric character

the `(` and `)` around the whole expression would permit you to catch the whole expression.

Since your content is around `[]` I have changed `.*` to `[^\]]` since the regular expression are **greedy** in case of `test2[.....] test3[sadsdasdasdad]` it would capture until the end since there is a `]`.

Also please note since you are using the `$` it will match always things in the end, I am not really sure if it's what you intend to do.

You can see [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for reference.